# Angularjs paging limit data load

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I always manage pagination with angular

retrieve all the data from the server

and cache it client side (simply put it in a service)

now I have to cope with quite lot of data

ie 10000/100000.

I'm wondering if can get into trouble

using the same method.

Imo passing parameter to server like

page search it's very annoying for a good

user experience.

**UPDATE** (for the point in the comment)

So a possible way to go
could be get from the server

like 1000 items at once if the user go too close

to the offset (ie it's on the 800 items)

retrieve the next 1000 items from the server

merge cache  and so on

**it's quite strange not even ng-grid manage pagination
sending parameters to the server**

**UPDATE**

I ended up like:

```
(function(window, angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('my.modal.stream',[])
        .provider('Stream', function() {
            var apiBaseUrl = null;
            this.setBaseUrl = function(url) {
                apiBaseUrl = url;
            };
            this.$get = function($http,$q) {
                return {
                    get: function(id) {
                        if(apiBaseUrl===null){
                            throw new Error('You should set a base api url');
                        }
                        if(typeof id !== 'number'){
                            throw new Error('Only integer is allowed');
                        }
                        if(id < 1){
                            throw new Error('Only integer greater than 1 is allowed');
                        }
                        var url = apiBaseUrl + '/' + id;
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        $http.get(url)
                            .success(function (response) {
                                deferred.resolve(response);
                            })
                            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                deferred.reject([]);
                            });
                        return deferred.promise; 
                    }
                };
            };
    });
})(window, angular);
(function(window, angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('my.mod.pagination',['my.mod.stream'])
        .factory('Paginator', function(Stream) {
            return function(pageSize) {
                    var cache =[];
                    var staticCache =[];
                    var hasNext = false;
                    var currentOffset= 0;
                    var numOfItemsXpage = pageSize;
                    var numOfItems = 0;
                    var totPages = 0;
                    var currentPage = 1;
                    var end = 0;
                    var start = 0;
                    var chunk = 0;
                    var currentChunk = 1;
                    var offSetLimit = 0;
                    var load = function() {
                        Stream.get(currentChunk).then(function(response){
                            staticCache = _.union(staticCache,response.data);
                            cache = _.union(cache,response.data);
                            chunk = response.chunk;
                            loadFromCache();
                        });
                    };
                    var loadFromCache= function() {
                        numOfItems = cache.length;
                        offSetLimit = (currentPage*numOfItemsXpage)+numOfItemsXpage;
                        if(offSetLimit  > numOfItems){
                            currentChunk++;
                            load();

                        }
                        hasNext = numOfItems > numOfItemsXpage;
                        totPages = Math.ceil(numOfItems/numOfItemsXpage);
                        paginator.items = cache.slice(currentOffset, numOfItemsXpage*currentPage);
                        start = totPages + 1;
                        end = totPages+1;
                        hasNext = numOfItems > (currentPage * numOfItemsXpage);
                    };
                    var paginator = {
                        items : [],
                        notFilterLabel: '',
                        hasNext: function() {
                            return hasNext;
                        },
                        hasPrevious: function() {
                            return currentOffset !== 0;
                        },
                        hasFirst: function() {
                           return currentPage !== 1; 
                        },
                        hasLast: function() {
                           return totPages > 2 && currentPage!==totPages; 
                        },
                        next: function() {
                            if (this.hasNext()) {
                                currentPage++;
                                currentOffset += numOfItemsXpage;
                                loadFromCache();
                            }
                        },
                        previous: function() {
                            if(this.hasPrevious()) {
                                currentPage--;
                                currentOffset -= numOfItemsXpage;
                                loadFromCache();
                            }
                        },
                        toPageId:function(num){
                            currentPage=num;
                            currentOffset= (num-1) * numOfItemsXpage;
                            loadFromCache();
                        },
                        first:function(){
                            this.toPageId(1);
                        },
                        last:function(){
                            this.toPageId(totPages);
                        },
                        getNumOfItems : function(){
                            return numOfItems;
                        },
                        getCurrentPage: function() {
                            return currentPage;
                        },
                        getEnd: function() {
                            return end;
                        },
                        getStart: function() {
                            return start;
                        },
                        getTotPages: function() {
                            return totPages;
                        },
                        getNumOfItemsXpage:function(){
                            return numOfItemsXpage;
                        },
                        search:function(str){
                            if(str===this.notFilterLabel){
                                if(angular.equals(staticCache, cache)){
                                    return;
                                }
                                cache = staticCache;
                            }
                            else{
                                cache = staticCache;
                                cache = _.filter(cache, function(item){ return item.type == str; });
                            }
                            currentPage = 1;
                            currentOffset= 0;
                            loadFromCache();
                        }
                    };
                    load();
                    return paginator;
                 }
            });

})(window, angular);
```

server side with  laravel (All the items are cached)

```
public function tag($page)
    {

        $service = new ApiTagService(new ApiTagModel());
        $items = $service->all();
        $numOfItems = count($items);
        if($numOfItems > 0){
            $length = self::CHUNK;
            if($length > $numOfItems){
                $length = $numOfItems;
            }
            $numOfPages = ceil($numOfItems/$length);
            if($page > $numOfPages){
                $page = $numOfPages; 
            }
            $offSet = ($page - 1) * $length;
            $chunk = array_slice($items, $offSet, $length);
            return Response::json(array(
                    'status'=>200,
                    'pages'=>$numOfPages,
                    'chunk'=>$length,
                    'data'=> $chunk
                ),200);
        }
        return Response::json(array(
                    'status'=>200,
                    'data'=> array()
                ),200);
    }
```

The only trouble by now is managing filter
I've no idea how to treat filtering :(

Comment: You can keep a reasonable buffer around the page where the user is. (S)he wouldn't notice when you add to the end of the buffer and remove from the front (or vice versa)

Comment: it's about my same idea I think of but it's quite tricky to manage. (btw you mean retrieve form the server chunk of data like 1000 items once and than if the user go ahed seeing data delete  cache and retrieve the next chunk of data)

Comment: Maybe I'm underthinking it, but I figure if you ask the paging-service for page X, and X is getting too close to one end of the buffer, then the service moves the buffering window by retrieving posts beyond that end and throwing away some on the other. You don't even need to do it at each paging-request, just when you get too close to the end.

Comment: IMO, some portion of the paging is going to have to be handled by the server. Also, be sure to check out the max number of records a user can view on their screen at once. If the max is 50, pull 200. Show the first 50, page through the next 150, then load the next 200.

Comment: I've update the post what do you think about it ?